# Bootstrap 3 Collapse Menu is not expanding in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

On my website http://www.jeremiahlangner.com, when the menu is collapsed, the menu toggle button does not appear, nor does the menu expand when it is clicked. After replacing the code a few times, checking the order of how the javascript is loaded, and checking my css, I have still been unable to ascertain what is causing the problem. Can anyone offer any insight as to why it is still not functioning correctly?

Code is as follows:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>

    <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'              => 'primary',
            'theme_location'    => 'primary',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'div',
            'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
    ?>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your snippet isn't running properly. Also, what's your CSS for positioning the collapsed menu icon used to expand the list items?

Comment: All of the positioning is bootstrap default.

Comment: Why do you have an ID named "bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" for your collapsed menu? I can't find its reference in your js or css files.

Comment: The above code was adapted from the default twitter bootstrap navigation bar code. Note the button's "data-target" is the collapsible menu's id.

Answer (score 0):

you just missed the bootstrap js,add this line to your code:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The bootstrap script is properly loaded using Wordpress's "enqueue_script" function; this allows the menu to "collapse" in the first place when the window is resized. However, the menu icon doesn't "appear," and the menu doesn't expand out when it is clicked.

Comment: add "navbar-inverse" class to nav element,<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

Comment: Thanks Timber. Nice point, but not necessarily the solution for the collapse issue.